# CSS no Chrome não funciona corretamente

Tags: css, google-chrome

Estou a programar em PHP, HTML e Javascript para criar uma loja on-line, integrada na plataforma Opencart. Está tudo já a funcionar corretamente, menos um pequeno pormenor com as CSS. Coloquei o efeito `hover` na imagem dos diferentes produtos simplesmente usando `image a:hover`. No entanto, apesar de funcionar em todos os browsers, em alguma páginas do site no Chrome, o efeito não é executado!

---

```
.box-product .image {
    /**display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;**/
    margin-bottom: 22px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    /**box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #AAA inset**/
    border: 0px solid white;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.box-product .image img {
    padding: 3px;
    border: 0px solid #E7E7E7;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin:auto;

}

.box-product .image a:hover {
    opacity:0.5; filter:alpha(opacity=50);    
}
```

Comment: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: .box-product .image {
    /**display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;**/
    margin-bottom: 22px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;/**box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #AAA inset**/
border: 0px solid white;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;}.box-product .image a:hover {opacity:0.5; filter:alpha(opacity=50);}

Comment: Copiar este codigo no Validator do W3C vai dar a resposta (que tem a ver com a opacity)

Comment: Poderia postar o html? A imagem está, dentro da ancora ou fora?

Answer (score 1):

Testei aqui e funcionou, porem podem ser erro relacionado ao seu html e não exatamente a seu css.

Outra possibilidade de nao funcionamente é que segundo a W3C, a propriedade css opacity só funciona apartir da versão 4 do google chrome. Veja https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp

Caso continue nao funcionando, poste seu código HTML.

De qualquer forma deixo o exemplo postado que funcionou aqui.

```css
.box-product .image a:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: Alpha(opacity=50); /* IE8 and earlier */
    }
```

```html
<div class="box-product">
<div class="image">
<a href="#">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_chrome.gif" alt="Smiley face"/></a>
</div>
```